# Modify the top of stack without access to StackType object

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

I had a certain query regarding a question I was asked earlier.

I was given this function prototype `void StackPop(NodeType *Top)` and was told modify the top of the stack without access to the stack object. `StackPop` function here is a global function and not a member function of the Stack class. After popping, Top should point to  the new value of Top element.

As a solution, popping the top of the stack in such a case would only be possible if we pass the address of the top node of the stack to the function while calling. eg: `StackPop(&address);`
To modify the top of the stack

```
NodeType* temp;
temp = top;
*top = (*top)->next;
delete temp;
```

Is this the simple answer to the question or is something else the case that has to be taken care of?

Comment: Is your function argument `Node` or `NodeType`?

Comment: @Als: Editted. Yes, it is `NodeType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid simple answer to the question, with three caveats:

1. `temp = top` should read `temp = *top`;
2. you might want to gracefully handle the case where `*top` is NULL (rather than just dereferencing the NULL pointer);
3. this solution is of course incompatible with the prototype you were given [`void StackPop(Node *Top)`] as it would take `Node**` as its argument.

The only other remark that I have is that `StackPop` sounds like it ought to be a member function rather than a free function.

Comment: Yes, it is a free function rather than a class member function but will that affect the functionality of popping as written above (provided we ignore the fact that we would have to pass the address of top node)?

Comment: @Cipher: No, no difference in functionality. Just arguably poor design.

Comment: Would it be possible without modifying the prototype in any way i.e not even changing to StackPop(NodeType** node)?